# keras unable to call model.predict_classes for multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction

```
def predictOne(imgPath):

    model = load_model("withImageMagic.h5")
    image = read_image(imgPath)
    test_sample = preprocess(image)
    predicted_class = model.predict_classes(([test_sample]))
    return predicted_class
```

I have already trained a model. In this function, I load my model, read a new image, do some preprocessing and finally predict its label.

When I run my main.py file, this function is called and everything goes smoothly. However, after a couple of seconds, this function will be called again with another image and I get this error:

> ```
> 'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(5, 5, 1, 32), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

It's very strange that the function only works the first time. I tested multiple images and got the same behavior.

Windows 10 - tensorflow-gpu with keras

Comment: try loading model from file outside the function, and give the `model` object as argument to the function `def predictOne(imgPath, model)`. This will also be much faster. If you want to keep loading model inside the function, use `from keras import backend as K; K.clear_session()` before loading the model.

Comment: It worked. Post it as an answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: Ok, great! I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading model from file outside the function, and give the model object as argument to the function `def predictOne(imgPath, model)`. This will also be much faster, since the weights don't need to be loaded from disk every time a prediction is needed.

If you want to keep loading model inside the function, import the backend:

```
from keras import backend as K
```

and then

```
K.clear_session()
```

before loading the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
class one_model:
    session = None
    graph = None 
    loadModel = None
    __instance = None
    @staticmethod
    def getInstance(modelPath):
        """ Static access method. """
        if one_model.__instance == None:
            one_model.__instance = one_model(modelPath)
        return one_model.__instance
        
    def __init__(self, modelPath):
        self.modelPath = modelPath
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
        self.loadOneModel()
            
    def loadOneModel(self):
        try:
            with self.session.graph.as_default():
                K.set_session(self.session)
                self.loadModel = keras.models.load_model(self.modelPath)               
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            print(str(e))
                        
    def getPredictionOne(self, input_file_path): 
        #Predict the data once the model is loaded
        if self.loadModel is not None and self.session is not None: 
            try:
                image = load_img(input_file_path, target_size=inputShape)
                image = img_to_array(image)
                image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
                image = preprocess(image)
                with self.session.graph.as_default():
                    K.set_session(self.session)
                    preds = self.loadModel.predict(image)
                    return preds
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(str(e))
        
        return -1


if __name__== "__main__": 
    #First Model 
    data = web.input()
        fileapth = data.imagefilepath  
        modelfilepath = data.modelfilepath
        one_modelObj = one_model.getInstance(modelfilepath)        
        value = one_modelObj.getPredictionOne(fileapth)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!